# issue while running git Actions Job related to chrome driver version

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, npm, selenium-chromedriver, github-actions

package.json dependencies :

```
 "engines": {
    "npm": "6.14.17",
    "node": "14.20.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.20.7",
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.12",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.9.0",
    "@babel/register": "^7.9.0",
    "@rpii/wdio-html-reporter": "^1.0.3",
    "@wdio/cli": "^6.12.1",
    "@wdio/devtools-service": "^6.12.1",
    "@wdio/jasmine-framework": "^6.11.0",
    "@wdio/local-runner": "^6.12.1",
    "@wdio/mocha-framework": "^6.11.0",
    "@wdio/selenium-standalone-service": "^6.12.1",
    "@wdio/spec-reporter": "^6.11.0",
    "@wdio/sync": "^6.11.0",
    "chromedriver": "^110.0.0",
    "edgedriver": "^4.17134.1",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-wdio": "^6.6.0",
    "expect-webdriverio": "^1.4.1",
    "geckodriver": "^3.2.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "wdio-chromedriver-service": "^8.1.1",
    "wdio-html-reporter": "^1.0.2",
    "wdio-timeline-reporter": "^5.1.4",
    "webdriverio": "^6.12.1"
  },
```

my workflow file :

```
jobs:
  test:
    name: BUILD & TEST
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [14.x] 
    steps:  
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
    - name: Install
      run:  npm install
    - name: Run MWPL tests on staging environment
      run: ENV=staging HEADLESS=true npx wdio run wdio.conf.js --spec e2eScenario.spec.js
```

error :

```
[0-0] RUNNING in chrome - /test/e2eScenario.spec.js
[0-0] 2023-02-16T10:02:37.840Z ERROR webdriver: Request failed with status 500 due to session not created: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 110
Current browser version is 109.0.5414.119 with binary path /usr/bin/google-chrome
```

Logs of npm installing 110 chrome :

```
> chromedriver@110.0.0 install /home/runner/work/PlateRate-Tester/PlateRate-Tester/node_modules/chromedriver
> node install.js

Current existing ChromeDriver binary is unavailable, proceeding with download and extraction.
Downloading from file:  https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/110.0.5481.77/chromedriver_linux64.zip
Saving to file: /tmp/110.0.5481.77/chromedriver/chromedriver_linux64.zip
Received 1040K...
Received 2080K...
Received 3120K...
Received 4160K...
Received 5200K...
Received 6240K...
Received 7223K total.
Extracting zip contents to /tmp/110.0.5481.77/chromedriver.
Copying from /tmp/110.0.5481.77/chromedriver to target path /home/runner/work/PlateRate-Tester/PlateRate-Tester/node_modules/chromedriver/lib/chromedriver
Fixing file permissions.
Done. ChromeDriver binary available at /home/runner/work/PlateRate-Tester/PlateRate-Tester/node_modules/chromedriver/lib/chromedriver/chromedriver
```

on my local machine it works fine, but sounds like while executing the job the chrome version mentioned in package.json is not taken in considiration.
so why it says current browser version is 109 while in dependencies i have 110,
in logs clearly it installs 110 .

Comment: The default [preinstalled version](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/main/images/linux/Ubuntu2204-Readme.md#browsers-and-drivers) of Chrome driver on Ubuntu is 109. Have you verified that `npm install` actually works and installs 110? Your description says that it does install 100, please include those logs in your question as well.

Comment: I believe that `package.json` is being considered and it actually installs version 110 of the Chrome Driver. But, your workflow doesn't update Chrome browser itself which by default is 109.

Comment: @Azeem Done , as you said chrome 110 is installed with NPM but it lloks like it still uses preinstalled chrome of ubunto , so how to solve

Comment: logs added to post @Azeem ty

Comment: Thanks! You have to update the Chrome browser too. After that, it should work. This action (https://github.com/browser-actions/setup-chrome) looks relevant.

Comment: An alternative could be to run in a docker container e.g. https://hub.docker.com/layers/selenium/standalone-chrome/110.0/images/sha256-df7472a13463ff5e5e444bb485460ba1082c779469cbaa1f86b54997335761eb?context=explore.

Comment: @Azeem many thanks , also another possible solution is to set path variable in chrome options in wdio.conf.js so it will use the installed chromeinside node_modules and not ubunto

Comment: You're welcome! Yes, that could be a solution too. In the question, there is no mention of why 110 is required so I assumed that you were doing something in the code which only runs in 110 or later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [preinstalled versions](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/main/images/linux/Ubuntu2204-Readme.md#browsers-and-drivers) of Google Chrome browser and ChromeDriver are **109.0.5414.119** and **109.0.5414.74** respectively.

Seems like `npm install` is updating the ChromeDriver version only and the browser version is still 109. You need to update it accordingly or configure your CI to use the preinstalled versions.

This action might be helpful in this regard:
https://github.com/browser-actions/setup-chrome

Alternatively, you can use a docker container e.g. [selenium/standalone-chrome:110.0](https://hub.docker.com/layers/selenium/standalone-chrome/110.0/images/sha256-df7472a13463ff5e5e444bb485460ba1082c779469cbaa1f86b54997335761eb?context=explore).